# Adding a scroll bar for oversized picture to powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I have an oversized picture that I want to add to a powerpoint slide. I want the picture to fit within a box and have a vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for but you can make a faux scrolling bar with shapes and action buttons. The explanation for this is described in the Office page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-a-scrolling-effect-in-powerpoint-2007-HA010245145.aspx

This will allow you to get the feeling of a scrollbar. You can also add separate sections of the picture which becomes visible/invisible when you click the action button instead of showing the next page. You can alter the action by **right-clicking the action button and changing the action** or you could use a **regular button with the shape of an action button with an added hyperlink**.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is dead.